# Images displaying differently on chrome and firefox, sized using flexbox

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, flexbox

Okay so I made a photo gallery (I changed the pictures and captions in the code here), and used flexbox for arranging the photos and their descriptions on the left and right halves of the page alternatively. **This seemed to work perfectly in firefox, but when I tried to open it in chrome, the sizes of the images were not scaled properly and the page was all disproportionate.**

I even used a reset css file, but apparently that didn't work.

I can't seem to understand why it didn't work on chrome; I used the flexbox's "flex: 0 50%" to let the image and the caption(paragraph) take up their respective halves of the page.

I wasn't really expecting there to be any differences between chrome and firefox, both being very standard browsers. Also, I tried on three different PC's chrome browser(two on windows and one on ubuntu) and they all had the same issue. Why is this happening?

I'm kinda new to CSS so it'd be great if anyone could point out to any other issues in my code too, all comments are really welcome :)

I put this site on github so you can easily check it out: https://arushsharma24.github.io/chrome-firefox-imgs/index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <nav>
            <a href="#">Home</a>
            <a href="photos.html">Photo Gallery</a>
            <a href="#">More soon!</a>
    </nav>
    <div id="navOffset"></div>
    <header>
        <h1>Photo Gallery</h1>
        <p>A photo gallery</p>
    </header>
    <main>
        <img class="left" src="images/491050.jpg" alt="one">
        <p class="right">One</p>
        <p class="left">Two</p>
        <img class="right" src="images/853864.jpg" alt="two">
        <img class="left" src="images/858597.jpg" alt="there">
        <p class="right">Three</p>
        <p class='left'>Four</p>
        <img class="right" src="images/1053968.png" alt="four">
        <img class="left" src="images/IMG_20200530_142927.jpg" alt="five">
        <p class="right">Five</p>
        <p class="left">Six</p>
        <img class="right" src="images/wp2032040-sherlock-wallpapers.jpg" alt="six">
    </main>
    <div id="note">
        <p>Para para</p>
    </div>
    <footer>
        <p>footer text</p>
    </footer>
</body>
```

The reset CSS file I used

```
/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
```

The main CSS file:

```
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
nav {
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    display: flex;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: rgb(0, 36, 93);
}
#navOffset {
    z-index: -1;
    height: 100px;
}
nav a{
    /* border: solid white 0.01px; */
    padding: 1.5%;
    margin: auto;  
    text-decoration: none;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255); 
}
nav a:active{
    color: black;
}
nav a:hover{
    background-color: #ffffff;
    color: rgb(0, 36, 93);;
}
header{
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column;
}
header h1{
    margin: auto;
    flex:1;
    margin-bottom: 1%;
    margin-top: 2%;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 300%;
}
header p{
    flex:1;
    margin: auto;
    margin: 1% auto;
    font-size: 100%;
}
main{
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
}
main img{
    flex:1;
    padding: 2%;
    flex: 0 50%;
}
main p, div p{
    margin:1%;
    padding: 1%;
    flex:1;
    margin: auto;
    flex: 0 50%;

footer{
    width: 100%;
    padding: 2%;
    background-color: rgb(0, 36, 93);
    color: white;
    display: flex;
}
footer p{
    color: white;
    margin: auto;
}
```